# Transposing specific pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe  with values as below:-

```
data = {'Year': [2010, 2010, 2011, 2011,2012], 'Country': ['Germany', 'France', 'Germany', 'Afghanistan','Kosovo'],'Population':[20000000,30000000,20500000,2000000,60000]}
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The above is just a snippet of the data. The entire dataset has many more years  and other countries. All I need is have the below output as per the  above:-

```
Year  Germany    France     Afghanistan Kosovo 
2010 20000000    30000000      NaN       NaN
2011 20500000    NaN           2000000   NaN
2012  NaN        NaN           NaN       60000
```

The values for the years are  unique  ones  and population values matched as above. If the  population does not exist for a certain year that is present, then a NaN will be ideal.
How  can I transpose columns country and  population, leaving just year with its unique values?

I tried the below and it  basically transposes every column.

```
daraframe_transposed = data_df.T
```

Comment: `data_df.pivot(*df.columns)` should do it. `data_df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Country', values='Population')`